# CoreData Merge Change Weirdness

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm getting a weird zombie object issue when I'm trying to merge my changes from a background NSOperation:

```
(controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance)
```

I have a `ViewController` that pushes other controllers on a `navController` stack in my `AppDelegate` in the `didSelectRowForIndexPath` like so:

```
ABCViewController *myVC = [[ABCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABCViewController" bundle:nil];

ABCEvent *selectedEvent = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[myVC setManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[myVC setTitle:@"Title"];
[myVC setEvent:selectedEvent];

ABCAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ABCAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[appDelegate navController] pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
[myVC release];
```

Then in my `ViewDidLoad` for `ABCViewContoller` I'm creating an operation queue, and adding my background operation to it:

```
_operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

As well as hooking up a notification so I can merge the changes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(contextDidSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

All standard stuff I believe. The issue is if I select the row in the main VC, then go back to it, and hit the row again, I get that: **message sent to deallocated instance** message.  Now, if I turn off the notification for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, then I don't get the error, so that's definitely the culprit. My `dealloc` in my second controller is like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [_operationQueue release];
}
```

So I'm unhooking that class as an observer. In my mind it shouldn't be trying to merge changes on any unallocated instances. I believe somehow though it's trying to merge changes back in on the first instance of my controller when I touch the row again, even though I stopped subscribing to that notification.

I'm pretty stumped on this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a fetchedResultsControllerDelegate at all?

If you are, make sure to also set that to nil when the view disappears or unloads, otherwise it will continue to receive messages about changes in your data, regardless of removing the observer.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks. Totally rectified the situation!.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help, I have been burned by that a few times as well.

Answer (score 0):

One quick correction that should help is your `[super dealloc]` should **always** be the last statement in your `dealloc`.

Also, since you are doing CoreData operations on a background thread (via `NSOperationQueue`), make sure you are creating your `NSManagedObjectContext` for your background thread object **while in the background thread**. Do not create it on one thread and assign it to an object that will run in a different thread, or you will have all sorts of issues.

When you get your `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification, you need to do the merge on the same thread that the context you are merging **into** belongs on. More than likely this will be your main context in (it sounds like) your app delegate, which means it is on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually passing the MOC from the app delegate to the root view controller. Then passing the persistentStoreCoordinator to the NSOperations, and creating a new MOC there, using the PSC. Also yes, I'm doing the merge in the controller and not in the BG thread. Unfortunately the suggestion for the dealloc did not solve it, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sounds like your doing things right. How are you merging your changes? Are you using `-[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotificaion:]`?